# How to add live wallpaper/ animated background to my app? -Android

Tags: android, image, animation

Here's what I want to do...

Right now, I've got a few activities in my app with just some listviews and/or buttons in the whole screen...

The background is just black empty, so it looks very unprofessional, amateur and just awkward.
I don't want to do a static background, coz well I think seeing the same image everytime is very irritating.

So, I want something like a live wallpaper,  like the default ones  that come with Android. Then I can just set the alpha property of my buttons and listview and the whole app's look and feel will be awesome.

Can I retrieve the default android live wallpapers fron somewhere? If so, how?
Any other way to do it?
I need it to not lag, since my app is very light and I don't the peformance to suffer just because of the background.

(There is absolutely nothing on SO, or anywhere relating to this... So we need to come up with something new... I'm thinking maybe a gif or a video, but how to do it? idk)